ClientEncryption is undefined for mongoose 8 version library for CSFLE implemenation. what is the reason?
Integrating with MongoDB Client Side Field Level Encryption using mongoose 8 as per the below documentation mentioned in mongoose docs.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/field-level-encryption.html
When i am running the above script encryption object is not creating because ClientEncryption is undefined value from mongodb-client-encryption module.
i have used mongoose 8 version, mongodb 6 version and mongodb-client-encryption 6 version.
Please help to execute the script in the doc and also let me know why ClientEncryption is undefined.
